# Create 'fake' property that just sets property of a property

Tags: android, kotlin

Sorry for the wonky title, I have no idea how to properly word this. I've got the following situation: I have a class that has a Paint object for drawing something. I want the class to have the appearance of having a color field. Setting that field should just set the color of the stored Paint-Object and not actually set a field. In Java I would do it like this:

```
public class Foo {
    private Paint p;
    public void setColor(int color) {
        p.setColor(color);
    }
    public int getColor() {
        return p.getColor();
    }
}
```

Then I can access the color like a field of `Foo`, using setters and getters. How can I do this in kotlin so I can access the property Kotlin-style (like `myFoo.color = Color.RED`) and have it set the color property of Paint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at getters and setters in Kotlin:

```
class Foo {
    private var p: Paint? = null
    var color: Color
        set(value) { p.color = value }
        get() = p.color
}
```

To customize things.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html

Comment: The Paint also defines strokeWidth etc. which have to stay the same in this case. Only the color should be customizable. That is why the Paint can't be settable.

Comment: Ok so that's why you couldn't simply use `class Foo { var color: Paint }`. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this

```
class Foo {

private val p = Paint()

var color: Int
    get() = p.color
    set(value) {
        p.color = value
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

[Implementation by Delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html#implementation-by-delegation) is a common approach here. e.g. if `Paint` implemented an interface (e.g. `Paintable`) then you can make `Foo` take in an instance of `Paintable` and delegate all calls to it as follows:

```
interface Paintable { var color: Int }

class Paint(override var color: Int) : Paintable

class Foo(p: Paint) : Paintable by p
```